MPI_Wait does not free the MPI_Ibcast request
Consider the following program:
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>

int main() {
  int provided = -1;
  MPI_Init_thread(NULL, NULL, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided);

  if (provided != MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE) {
    return -1;
  }

  int this_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &this_rank);

  double aze[36864]{};
  MPI_Request req = MPI_REQUEST_NULL;

  std::cout << this_rank << " starting bcast" << std::endl;
  MPI_Ibcast(aze, 36864, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req);
  std::cout << this_rank << " req0 " << req << std::endl;

#pragma omp parallel
  {
    MPI_Status stat{};
    // do {
    MPI_Wait(&req, &stat);
    // } while(req != MPI_REQUEST_NULL);

    if (req != MPI_REQUEST_NULL) {
      std::cout << this_rank << " wait returned non null request: " << req
                << " vs " << MPI_REQUEST_NULL << std::endl;

      std::cout << this_rank << " MPI_SOURCE: " << stat.MPI_SOURCE << std::endl;
      std::cout << this_rank << " MPI_TAG: " << stat.MPI_TAG << std::endl;
      std::cout << this_rank << " MPI_ERROR: " << stat.MPI_ERROR << std::endl;
    }
  }

  {
    volatile int dummy = 0;
    while (dummy != 1'000'000'000) {
      dummy++;
    }
    std::cout << this_rank << " sleep done" << std::endl;
  }
  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}

I'm using OpenMPI 5.0.2. I used clang and gcc in their near latest release. I run and build the reproducer above like so:
$ g++ -fopenmp ~/Downloads/trash/repro.mpi.cc -isystem /usr/include/openmpi-x86_64 -L /usr/lib64/openmpi/lib/ -lmpi
$ export OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
$ mpirun -n 4 ./a.out

The expected stdout is (sorted by rank identifier):
0 starting bcast
0 req0 0x3e573f28
0 sleep done
1 starting bcast
1 req0 0x79d9298
1 sleep done
2 starting bcast
2 req0 0xc4841b8
2 sleep done
3 starting bcast
3 req0 0x2fdf2f18
3 sleep done

Note that the address may obviously change.
The observed behavior, is like so (again, sorted by rank identifier):
0 starting bcast
0 req0 0x25aa6f28
0 wait returned non null request: 0x25aa6f28 vs 0x4045e0
0 MPI_SOURCE: 0
0 MPI_TAG: 0
0 MPI_ERROR: 0
0 sleep done
1 starting bcast
1 req0 0xb169298
1 sleep done
2 starting bcast
2 req0 0xc4f81b8
2 wait returned non null request: 0xc4f81b8 vs 0x4045e0
2 MPI_SOURCE: 0
2 MPI_TAG: 0
2 MPI_ERROR: 0
2 sleep done
3 starting bcast
3 req0 0x10ccbf18
3 wait returned non null request: 0x10ccbf18 vs 0x4045e0
3 MPI_SOURCE: 0
3 MPI_TAG: 0
3 MPI_ERROR: 0
3 sleep done

What we observe is that while MPI_Wait returns, does not report any error in MPI_Status nor in the logs, the MPI_Request is not freed and set to MPI_REQUEST_NULL.
According to the OpenMPI doc and standard:
A call to MPI_Wait returns when the operation identified by request is complete. If the communication object associated with this request was created by a nonblocking send or receive call, then the object is deallocated by the call to MPI_Wait and the request handle is set to MPI_REQUEST_NULL. (https://docs.open-mpi.org/en/v5.0.x/man-openmpi/man3/MPI_Wait.3.html#description).
Is the code snippet above unsound ? Note that if the do/while loop around the MPI_Wait is uncommented, the the code then produces the output I expect. But then, it turns into MPI_Test's semantic (polling). The openmp bit is key to triggering the issue.

I am not sure if calling MPI_Wait() on the same request simultaneously by several threads is legit. I asked Open MPI devs on slack. FWIW, mpich (generally) crashes with 4 tasks and 4 threads per task.

This is interesting then, because, AFAIK, when one uses MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE we get the following semantic: If the process is multithreaded, multiple threads may call MPI at once with no restrictions. Which to be faire seems to hold, except that ones needs to poll on MPI_WAit ofr it the eventually show the expected result (block and release the request)

Well the "with no restrictions" does not include creating race conditions. But you raise an interesting point. Your code would work if MPI_Wait is atomic, or at least the updating of the request. I kinda doubt that.

Two threads can never invoke the same collective on the same communicator at the same time. So "with no restrictions" is obviously incorrect.

Same collective on the same communicator will end up being serialized, in which order, is unknown as is, but this is the app's responsibility to dictate in which order.
I conceptualize MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE as if having a big global lock around every MPI routines plus a thread dedicated to ensuring progress (aka calling some kind of opal_progress).
For instance, if I use MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED, I can change the code above and add a pragma omp critical and the code produces the expected result. I myself would expect THREAD_MULTIPLE to expose the same behavior as serialized with a lock around

Finally, in multithreaded implementations, one can have more than one, concurrently
executing, collective communication initialization call at an MPI process. In these situ-
ations, it is the user’s responsibility to ensure that the same communicator is not used
concurrently by two different collective communication initialization calls at the same MPI
process. Collective communication initialization calls include all calls for blocking collective
operations, all initiation calls for nonblocking collective operations, and all initialization
calls for persistent collective operations

MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE and progress threads are unrelated from the MPI standard point of view. The behavior you should expect is drafted in the MPI standard, don't make up your own stuff.

Everybody makes its own stuff, this is called interpretation. Now, mine is flawed. That said it derived from a pretty reasonable extension of MPI_THREAD_SERIALIZED with an "as if" lock around mpi calls.
Any way, what does the standard says about MPI_Wait, is it, by transitivity, part of "Collective communication initialization calls" ?

I guess I can pretend you are not arguing for the sake of arguing.
I mentioned one restriction that happened to apply to collectives operations. No valid logic can conclude that only collective operations have restrictions, so there is no point in associating MPI_Wait() with collective operations.

The relevant text is: "Multiple threads completing the same request. A program in which two threads block, waiting on the same request, is erroneous. Similarly, the same request cannot appear in the array of requests of two concurrent MPI_{WAIT|TEST}{ANY|SOME|ALL} calls. In MPI, a request can only be completed once. Any combination of wait or test that violates this rule is erroneous."

@Joachim thanks, just what I was looking for. The extent of MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE is more limited tohan what I had in mind. I guess the standardized behavior is like so to allow MPI implementations not to have to put a big global lock.

@Joachim please post that as the answer.

The relevant text is (copied from MPI 4.0, but similarly present in other versions):

Multiple threads completing the same request. A program in which two
threads block, waiting on the same request, is erroneous. Similarly,
the same request cannot appear in the array of requests of two
concurrent MPI_{WAIT|TEST}{ANY|SOME|ALL} calls. In MPI, a request can
only be completed once. Any combination of wait or test that violates
this rule is erroneous.

The only completion function that you can call concurrently with a pointer to the same request handle is MPI_Test. The important point there is that all threads really refer to the same storage for the common request handle.
